# Retrieve Video from media library

Tags: wordpress

I'm saving in an extra field at posts an attachment ID of videos from the media library. How can I display the embedded video (with poster) in the front end by the attachment id?

The problem is that I do not get the poster of the video in the front end. Somebody has some suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ACF for the custom fields ? Perhaps you can think of uploading the video to youtube / vimeo and use oEmbed

```
    <?php the_field('oembed'); ?>
```

And you will just put the link of the video in the backend which is easier.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, everything is working inside our custom plugin. I need a solution based on the attachment id.

Comment: @yfain I am not sure how are you trying to display your video on the frontend, with the standard <video> tag or something else .. ?

Comment: Yes, buut I don't get the image I've set as a poster for this video with wordpress. The best thing would be to get the video as Wordpress standard embedded vido